# Prove that $T$ is a bounded operator on a disk algebra and prove the existence of a Borel measure on a boundary of an open unit disk.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, holomorphic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $A(D)$ be the space of holomorphic functions on the open unit disk $D$ and continuous on the closed disk $\bar{D}$. Then $A(D)$ is a Banach space if we set $\|f\|=\sup\{|f(z)|:z\in\bar{D}\}$. For $f\in A(D)$ write
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.
$$
a) Let $\{c_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex numbers with the property that if $f\in A(D)$ represented as above, and 
$$
f^*(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_na_nz^n,
$$ 
then $f^*\in A(D)$. Prove that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|f^*\|\leq C\|f\|$ for all $f\in A(D)$.

I am thinking that I need to prove $T:A(D)\to A(D)$ with $T(f)=f^*$ is bounded (or continuous). Do you have any other ideas?

b) Let $\omega\in D$. Prove that there exists a Borel measure $\mu_{\omega}$ on $\partial D=\{z:|z|=1\}$ such that
$$
f(\omega)=\int_{\partial D}f(t)d\mu_{\omega}(t),\;f\in A.
$$

I am thinking that we can use the Maximum Modulus principle, but is the measure $\mu_{\omega}$ unique? Could you please give me some ideas?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hints; closed graph theorem for a), and Hahn-Banach theorem together with Riesz representation theorem for b) !

Comment: @BartoszMalman Maybe the Beppo-Necky theorem is more efficient here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a), use closed graph theorem to show $T$ is bounded. It suffices to show if $f_k \to f$ and $Tf_k = f_k^* \to g$ in $A(D)$, then $g= Tf = f^*$. It follows from Cauchy's integral formula
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
$$  and uniform convergence of $(f_k)$ and $(f^*_k)$. (Hint: compare coefficients of power series expansions of $f^*$ and $g$.)

For b), let $B(\mathbb{T})$ be a family of $g\in C(\mathbb{T})$ such that $g = f|_\mathbb{T}$ for some $f\in A(D)$. (Here, $\mathbb{T}=\partial D$.) Then, $B(\mathbb{T})$ is a subspace of $ C(\mathbb{T})$. Let
$$
\phi_\omega: g\in B(\mathbb{T}) \mapsto f(\omega)\in \mathbb{C}.
$$ Then, $\phi_\omega$ is a well-defined linear functional (since there is unique $f\in A(D)$ such that $g = f|_\mathbb{T}$) with $\|\phi_\omega\|_{B(\mathbb{T})\to \mathbb{C}}\leq 1$ by maximum modulus theorem. By Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists an extension $\Phi_\omega : C(\mathbb{T}) \to \mathbb{C}$ of $\phi_\omega$ with $\|\Phi_\omega\|_{C(\mathbb{T})\to \mathbb{C}}=\|\phi_\omega\|_{B(\mathbb{T})\to \mathbb{C}}$. Now, by Riesz representation theorem, we know there exists a finite Borel measure $\mu_\omega$ on $\mathbb{T}$ such that $$
\Phi_\omega(f|_\mathbb{T})=f(\omega) = \int_\mathbb{T} f|_\mathbb{T}(t)d\mu_\omega(t)=\int_\mathbb{T} f(t)d\mu_\omega(t)
$$ for all $f \in A(D)$.